# USB host for android

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to communicate with my freeduino board which is similar to arduino uno via usb through android device 'nexus 7' which has 4.2 (jelly beans) in it.[image: This is the photo of my freeduino board. It look exactly like this]

I used the developers guide to communicate with the device from a couple of months but with no result. I think i am missing something minute in it. I am trying to simply display the vendor id of my freeduino board. My manifest file look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usb_host_final_try"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.usb_host_final_try.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have created a file device_filter in res/xml dir. which look like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="0403" product-id="07d7" />
</resources>
```

and my MainActivity.java has the following code.

```
package com.example.usb_host_final_try;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");
        int vid=device.getVendorId();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(vid));
    }
```

please help me out i am screwed up over it from past few months now. I have tried doing this but it is also not working.

[link](http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/)

[link](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549)

[Stack overfolow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110555/how-to-detect-usb-device-in-android-tablet-which-acts-as-usb-host)

[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773561/putting-an-android-device-in-usb-host-mode)

I have tried all these and still haven't been able to succeed. I also tried to use an if else loop to see if enumeration works where i set the text to device not found if no device is else settext to vendor id. On emulator is showed no device found but on my tablet wen i connect the device it force closes or else it still shows no device found wen nothing is connected.

The stack trace is here..

> 01-05 09:10:35.364: W/Trace(1658): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-05 09:10:35.364: W/Trace(1658): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-05 09:10:35.464: W/Trace(1658): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-05 09:10:35.464: W/Trace(1658): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-05 09:10:35.624: D/AndroidRuntime(1658): Shutting down VM
>   01-05 09:10:35.624: W/dalvikvm(1658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.usb_host_final_try/com.example.usb_host_final_try.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.example.usb_host_final_try.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   01-05 09:10:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     ... 11 more
>   01-05 09:10:46.074: W/Trace(1712): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-05 09:10:46.074: W/Trace(1712): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-05 09:10:46.754: D/AndroidRuntime(1712): Shutting down VM
>   01-05 09:10:46.754: W/dalvikvm(1712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.usb_host_final_try/com.example.usb_host_final_try.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.usb_host_final_try.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   01-05 09:10:46.766: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     ... 11 more
>   01-05 09:10:49.104: I/Process(1712): Sending signal. PID: 1712 SIG: 9

Comment: Hello Sahil, I am doing communication between arduino and Android. I am using same board but communication not establishing. Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634930/arduino-to-android-turning-an-led-on-and-off-using-adk and Plz help me. I f you have any idea about this. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: first of all my name is Sohil. It clearly says that. secondly this board uses a ft232 usb it wont work with the android sdk. U need to go to use the api provided by ftdi to do this. I was successfull in establishing the connection and sending pulse so its 100% correct. Here's the link  [link](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main activity will now become like this and rest of it remains the same

```
    package com.example.usb_host_final_try;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final String TAG = null;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
            String s=device.getDeviceName();
            int pid= device.getProductId();
            int vid = device.getVendorId();
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
            tv.setText(s+"\n"+Integer.toString(pid)+"\n"+Integer.toString(vid));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

All thanks to oleg Vaskevich!!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: Permissions aren't actually needed if defined in XML, so the answer below does not apply. The issue was an NPE - no such device "deviceName" existed in the code.

---

It looks like you are not obtaining permission to use the USB accessory, as described [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#permission-a) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11020806/832776).

In your `onCreate()`:

```
UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
    "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
...
mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

In your `Activity`:

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
    "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(accessory != null){
                        //call method to set up accessory communication
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for accessory " + accessory);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To show the dialog to get permission:

```
UsbAccessory accessory;
...
mUsbManager.requestPermission(accessory, mPermissionIntent);
```

Comment: i read in a note on developer that if i include intent filter in the manifest i don have to get permissions and that permissions are granted automatically..

Comment: If your application uses an intent filter to discover accessories as they're connected, it automatically receives permission if the user allows your application to handle the intent. If not, you must request permission explicitly in your application before connecting to the accessory. THIS IS WHAT IS WRITTEN THERE.. DOES IT MEAN THE SAME THING THAT I JUST SAID?

Comment: Yes it does. You said the app force closes? Post the stack trace.

Comment: There's a `NullPointerException` on `com.example.usb_host_final_try.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)`. Which line is that?

Comment: int vid=device.getVendorId();

Comment: how can i display the vendorId otherwise??

Comment: That means `device` is null, which means `deviceList.get("deviceName");` is returning null. Did you make sure that "deviceName" is valid?

Comment: ya i get the problem... i have not set the devicename but how do i find the devicename of this board.

Comment: also i noticed the vendorId remains contant but the product id is not constant.. I am use usb device info app for getting this information.. sometimes it shows 07d2 and sometimes 07d7 .. also i used usbView and in that the productId is shown as 6001... i am totally confused now... in the linux section of usb device info it again shows 6001 as productid..

Comment: `deviceList` is just a `HashMap<String, UsbDevice>`... I suggest you start by looping through each `UsbDevice` and printing out its properties and key name to determine the name you need.

Comment: ok got my fault thank you so much... i appreciate your time and help..:)