# Arduino to Android – Turning an LED On and Off using ADK

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I am referring [this](http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/arduino-to-android-turning-led-on-and_29.html) example for communicating Android with Arduino board. I am having freeduino uno board with USB shield and Android phone(micromax A110 (4.1.1), sony xperia P (4.0.6) and samsumg core (4.1.2)). I have downloaded USB_Host_Shield_2.0 from [here](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0). I am compiling sketch and uploading successfully. but, unable to establish communication between freeduino uno board and Android phone. I am trying to blink LED using PIN 13 of freduino uno board but its not working. I am getting output on serial monitor after connecting Android phone to freeduino board.

```
ADK demo start
Waits for Android device get ready.
Waits for Android device get ready.
Waits for Android device get ready.
Waits for Android device get ready.
Waits for Android device get ready.

ADK Init
ADK Init
ADK protocol rev. 0002

swAcc:
ADK Init
getDevDescr 0D

ADK Init
getDevDescr 0D

ADK Init
getDevDescr 0D
```

If I am connecting Android phone(v4.0.3) with freeduino board i am getting below error on serial monitor

```
Device addressed... Requesting device descriptor.
found possible device. swithcing to serial mode
device supports protocol 1 or higher
Data packet error: D
Data packet error: D
```

Thank you in Advance..

Comment: Are you using the same usb host shield?

Comment: @Dage: I am using freeduino USB Host shield.

Comment: I'm not sure if the firmware is compatible with that board?
These links might be helpfull: https://github.com/moderndevice/FreeduinoHostBoard/tree/master/Freeduino_USB_Host_Board
http://wiki.moderndevice.com/pmwiki.php?n=MD.FHB

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried but giving me same error. may be my devices not supporting to accessory devices

Comment: I havent used it myself, but it should be compatible.
From http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html
Start Google Play on your device, search for the ADK 2012 application and install it. If you cannot find the app, your device is not compatible. Try installing on another device.

I would just follow that guide to get your device to connect before moving on..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it could be a few things. For this problem, it might help you to press the reset button a couple of times on the arduino board, then try again. Also, when you connect the shield, try connecting pin d7 to the reset pin on the arduino board. If this doesn't solve it, then you likely have a problem with your usb shield, but maybe someone else has a better answer for you, let me know if this helps!

Comment: You are using an [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable or adapter?